# Java audio effects - Distortion algorithm on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing

I'm working on an application for android that does some real-time processing of audio from the mic. The sampling and playback is working effectively, but I am having difficulty with implementing the first audio effect - distortion. The audio comes in buffers of shorts, so each time one of these is received I attempt to map the values to the full size of a signed short, and then essentially clip these values if they are above a certain level. The audio that comes from this is certainly distorted, but not in a desirable way. I've included my code for accomplishing this. Can anyone see an error here?

```
public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            short max = maxValue(buffers[ix]);
            short multiplier;

            if(max!=0)
                multiplier = (short) (0x7fff/max);
            else
                multiplier = 0x7fff;
            double distLvl =.8;
            short distLvlSho = 31000;
            short max2 =100;
        for(int i=0;i<buffers[ix].length;i++){
            buffers[ix][i]=(short) (buffers[ix][i]*multiplier);
            if(buffers[ix][i]>distLvlSho)
                buffers[ix][i]=distLvlSho;
            else if(buffers[ix][i]<-distLvlSho)
                buffers[ix][i]=(short)-distLvlSho;
            buffers[ix][i]=(short) (buffers[ix][i]/multiplier);
        }
```

The buffers array is a 2D array of shorts, and the processing is to be done on just one of the array-within-arrays, here buffers[ix].

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see in the end what you get is just a  clipping of the source with a clip threshold which follows the proportion clipThr/max(input)=distLvlSho/0x7fff. most of the input this way is basically unchanged.

If you actually wanted to distort the signal you should apply some kind nonlinear function to the whole signal (plus eventually clipping near sample max to simulate the analog saturation)

A few simple models for distortion are listed in this book : http://books.google.it/books?id=h90HIV0uwVsC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

The simplest is a simmetrical soft clipping (see page 118). Here's your method modified with that soft clip function, see if it fits your needs for distorted sound (I tested it by making up a few sinusoids on input and using excel to plot the output)

In the same chapter you'll find a simple tube modeling and a fuzz filter modeling (there are a few exponentials on those so if performance is an issue you might want to approximate those).

```
    public void onMarkerReachedSoftClip(short[] buffer) {
    double th=1.0/3.0; 
     double multiplier = 1.0/0x7fff; // normalize input to double -1,1
     double out = 0.0;
     for(int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++){
        double in = multiplier*(double)buffer[i];
        double absIn = java.lang.Math.abs(in);
        if(absIn<th){
            out=(buffer[i]*2*multiplier);
        }
        else if(absIn<2*th){
            if(in>0)out= (3-(2-in*3)*(2-in*3))/3;
            else if(in<0)out=-(3-(2-absIn*3)*(2-absIn*3))/3;
        }
        else if(absIn>=2*th){
            if(in>0)out=1;
            else if(in<0)out=-1;
        }
        buffer[i] = (short)(out/multiplier);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply 2 short integers, the result requires a long integer or the result can overflow.

e.g. 1000 * 1000 = 1000000 , which is too big for a 16-bit short integer.

So you need to perform a scaling operation (divide or right shift) **before** you convert the multiplication result to a short value for storage.  Something like:

```
result_short = (short)( ( short_op_1 * short_op_2 ) >> 16 );
```

Comment: Should have mentioned this, the maxValue function used at the beginning finds the maximum of the array I'm working with, so multiplier short should multiply the values in the array to at the most the limit of values a short can hold, 32767.